# Como criar Permissões (Permissions) de verdade ao invés de simples Papéis (Roles) no Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Estou desenvolvendo um módulo de Controle de Acesso para minha aplicação web usando o Spring Security (3.1.4 - a última *release*) e esbarrei numa limitação no mecanismo de **Autorização**, pois o framework somente prevê o uso de *Roles* (papéis), o que significa que somente posso especificar que o usuário *tem* ou *não tem* um determinado papel.

Porém, os requisitos do Controle de Acesso exigem o uso de permissões, inclusive com hierarquia.

Suponha que meu sistema eu tenha usuários os perfis `Aluno`, `Professor` e `Diretor`. Dada uma  tela administrativa X, `Aluno` tem a permissão *negada* (false), `Professor` não tem a permissão *indefinida* (null) e `Diretor` tem a permissão *concedida* (true).

Mas o sistema permite dar permissões específicas aos usuários, além dos perfis. Se eu conceder a permissão à tela X a um usuário no perfil `Aluno`, ele não terá a permissão pois o perfil já negou e possui prioridade. Se conceder ao `Professor` ele passará a ter acesso à tela X, pois o perfil não definiu se ele poderia ou não ter o acesso. Se conceder ao `Diretor` ele simplesmente continuará tendo acesso, pois não afeta a permissão definida no perfil.

---

Traduzindo tudo isso em termos mais técnicos, eu preciso estender o mecanismo de Autorização do Spring Security com um algoritmo em particular.

Obviamente eu já li toda a documentação do Spring Security, embora as melhores referências sejam de outros blogs, mas ainda não consegui extrair de tudo isso uma boa estratégia para resolver a questão.

Existe algum mecanismo no Spring Security, que eu possa sobrescrever, onde possa implementar um método onde tenha acesso ao contexto (HttpSession, por exemplo) e possa retornar `true` ou `false` sempre que o usuário tentar acessar um recurso protegido ou o método `hasRole()` for chamado?

Comment: Não sei se é bem isso que você está pensando, ma aqui no trampo o pessoal optou por usar a autenticação pelo spring e autorização por RBAC. Existe um artigo em inglês que nos ajudou bastante(apesar de estarmos no br.stack vou sugerir esse artigo pois nos ajudou a definir isso) http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/

Comment: +1 no que o @meurer falou. Infelizmente muitos frameworks encorajam modelos de autorização baseados em roles que são difíceis de aplicar pra solucionar os problemas desse tipo que você está enfrentando, que são requisitos comuns. Uma ideia é usar Spring Security para autenticação/autorização básicas e implementar um outro método de autorização baseado no RBAC.

Comment: Obrigado @meurer, é um ótimo artigo, embora não seja 100% aplicável em minha situação atual, pois a definição conceitual já está fechada e meu problema é mais técnico no que se refere às limitações do framework. e elias, é verdade, em meu código atual já estou praticamente refazendo toda a lógica de autorização do Spring, mas está me parecendo intrusivo demais, pois alterações no framework vão provavelmente quebrar minhas implementações. De qualquer forma agraço pelos comentários.

Comment: Talvez o que você queira é criar um próprio decision manager, extendendo a AbstractAccessDecisionManager. Veja o 13.2.2 do http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/authz-arch.html#authz-access-voting

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## O sistema de decisão do Spring Framework

Após uma análise mais profunda da estrutura do Spring resolvi a questão com um Spring Bean que implementa a interface [`AccessDecisionVoter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html). Um *Voter* (Votador) é uma classe que que o Spring invoca para dizer se determinada *credencial* pode acessar determinado *recurso* num determinado *contexto*.

O Spring permite encadear (*chain*) diversos *Voters* para tomar uma certa decisão. Cada *Voter* vota a favor, contra ou se abstém da decisão. A decisão final é do `AccessDecisionManager`, que possui as seguintes implementações:

- `AffirmativeBased`: permite o acesso se pelo menos um *Voter* votou a favor.
- `UnanimousBased`: permite o acesso apenas se todos votaram a favor, ignorando as abstenções.
- `ConsensusBased`: permite ou nega o acesso de acordo com a maioria.

Dessa forma, eu posso implementar diferentes *Voters* que respondem a diferentes situações e se abstém das demais. Além disso, escolho a estratégia de decisão que melhor se enquadra ao meu sistema.

As afirmações acima podem ser melhores compreendidas com o diagrama a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação: foi me dada a sugestão de estender `AccessDecisionManager`, o que resolveria o problema, mas ao mesmo tempo sobrescreveria *praticamente por completo* o Spring Security. Então pareceu-me melhor atuar num ponto mais específico.

## Implementação

Criar um *Voter* não é uma tarefa complexa, mas foram necessários vários testes para entender bem o funcionamento, os valores recebidos nos parâmetros e o comportamento em geral do framework, pois não há uma documentação detalhada sobre isso. Abaixo está uma implementação simplificada do que fiz, sem código específico do meu domínio:

```java
public class CustomVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object> {

    final protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {

        logger.info("### Controle de Acesso  ###");

        //verifica se as credenciais são do tipo esperado
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof CustomUserDetails) {

            CustomUserDetails user = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            GerenciadorPermissao gerenciadorPermissao = user.getGerenciadorPermissao();

            //variável de sessão (HTTP) armazenada numa determinada tela via JSF
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
            Integer variavelSessao = (Integer) session.getAttribute("variavelSessao");

            Boolean result = null;
            for (ConfigAttribute configAttribute : attributes) {

                String attr = configAttribute.getAttribute();
                if (attr.equals("ROLE_USER")) {
                    //ROLE_USER é a ROLE de usuário, logado, então retorna true sempre
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    //chama uma lógica específica que verifica se o usuário possui permissão no contexto atual
                    result = gerenciadorPermissao.verificarPermissao(variavelSessao, attr);
                }

            }

            if (result == null || result == Boolean.FALSE) {
                logger.info(" -> Acesso Negado!");
                return ACCESS_DENIED;
            } else {
                logger.info(" -> Acesso Permitido!");
                return ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println(" -> Não é do tipo CustomUserDetails!");
            return ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

    }

}
```

Alguns pontos relevantes do código acima:

- O método `vote()` é chamado pelo Spring sempre que ele precisa tomar uma decisão.
- O primeiro parâmetro, do tipo `Authentication`, retorna informações sobre o login atual.
- O método `getPrincipal` da instância de `Authentication` retorna as informações do usuário que eu defini no momento do login. No caso é uma instância de `CustomUserDetails`, que implementa a interface `UserDetails` do Spring.
- Como pode ser visto, não é nada complicado acessar valores da sessão (`HttpSession`) em sistemas web com JSF.
- O parâmetro do tipo `Object` retorna o recurso sendo acessado. Dependendo do contexto, pode ser a URL de uma página, pode ser uma referência a um método, etc.
- O último parâmetro contém uma lista dos atributos, regras ou papéis que devem ser verificadas.

## Configuração

O documento XML a seguir é uma simplificação da configuração do Spring Security usada na minha aplicação. Publiquei-o na íntegra, pois em alguns exemplos que encontrei em outros sites não ficava claro como um *bean* se relacionava com os demais.

Em suma, a configuração contém:

- Definições gerais do Spring Security.
- Declaração do *Voter* e a respectiva associação com um `AccessDecisionManager` do tipo `UnanimousBased`.
- Segurança de algumas páginas associadas ao `AccessDecisionManager` declarado.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Configura o servlet filter do Spring Security -->
    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <filter-chain filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter" pattern="/**" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <beans:property name="forceEagerSessionCreation" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configura handlers para sucesso de autenticação, falha de autenticação e acesso negado a um determinado recurso -->
    <beans:bean
        id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="br.com.starcode.commons.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:bean
        id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        class="br.com.starcode.commons.security.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    <beans:bean
        id="customAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="br.com.starcode.commons.security.CustomAccessDeniedHandler" />

    <!-- Voter customizado -->
    <beans:bean id="customVoter" class="br.com.starcode.commons.security.CustomVoter" />

    <!-- Define AccessDesisionManager como UnanimousBased e coloca o Voter na lista -->
    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <beans:ref bean="customVoter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configura a criptografia (hash) da senha -->
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:value>11</beans:value>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configura o AuthenticationManager com os beans da aplicação -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="accessControlService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- Não coloca segurança em Javascript, CSS e outros recursos "estáticos" do JSF -->
    <http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />

    <!-- Não coloca segurança na tela de login -->
    <http pattern="/login.xhtml*" security="none" />

    <!-- Define a segurança para os demais recursos -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">

        <!-- Referência ao controlador de Acesso Negado -->
        <access-denied-handler ref="customAccessDeniedHandler" />

        <!-- Informações da página de login e dos handlers de sucesso e falha -->
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login.xhtml"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

        <!-- Página de logout, desloga o usuário ao ser chamada -->
        <logout logout-url="/logout.xhtml" />

        <!-- Acesso à página inicial para qualquer usuário logado -->
        <intercept-url access="ROLE_USER" pattern="/index.xhtml*" />

        <!-- permissões específicas para as telas -->
        <intercept-url access="permissao.tela.1" pattern="/tela1.xhtml" />
        <intercept-url access="permissao.tela.2" pattern="/tela2.xhtml" />
        <intercept-url access="permissao.tela.N" pattern="/telaN.xhtml" />

        <!-- nega acesso a qualquer outra tela -->
        <intercept-url access="NO_ACCESS" pattern="/**.xhtml" />

    </http>

    <!-- Permite anotar métodos -->
    <global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled"
        jsr250-annotations="enabled"
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Como não obtive nenhuma resposta efetiva, tive que marcar a minha própria como certa. Mas agradeço a todos os que comentaram e compartilharam informações relevantes.

Comment: Estou precisando implementar uma segurança atraves de spring, só que não posso trabalhar com regras. mas permissões a nivel de tela (xhtml). Vi este sua postagem, e não entendi completamente seu post. mas resumindo.. esta sua implementação resolveria em partes meu problema?

Comment: @rodrigoCristoFuhr Não faz diferença se você aplica a segurança a um método, URL ou botão numa tela. Tudo o que você precisa fazer é atribuir ao usuário um conjunto de permissões e associar cada permissão a um elemento do sistema. Nas telas você pode verificar se o usuário tem uma permissão X através de taglibs. [Veja a documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html). Se tiver mais dúvidas, [pergunte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)! Abraço!

Comment: Voce poderia postar a classe CustomUserDetails e a classe GerenciadorPermissao

Comment: Isso é muito interessante. É apenas como Symfony Framework faz (à propósito, os componentes de segurança do Symfony baseiam-se no Spring) através de [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html). Eles podem substituir ACL em vários cenários.

Answer (score 4):

Salve, @utluiz!

Eu não tenho reputação o suficiente para fazer um comentário, mas gostaria de deixar a minha contribuição.

Você deu uma olhada no [Spring Security ACL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls)?

> Complex applications often will find the need to define access permissions not simply at a web request or method invocation level. Instead, security decisions need to comprise both who (`Authentication`), where (`MethodInvocation`) and what (`SomeDomainObject`). In other words, authorization decisions also need to consider the actual domain object instance subject of a method invocation.

Acredito que ele pode ajudar na sua implementação já que trabalha diretamente no relacionamento do domínio com o usuário. Dessa forma você pode restringir o acesso diretamente ao recurso. Inclusive há uma taglib interessante para a verificação de acesso dos usuários.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#entityId, 'EntityClass', 'read')")
@RequestMapping("/entities/{entityId}") 
public String fetchEntity(@PathVariable("entityId") String entityId) {...}
```

*Exemplo retirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661735/spring-security-acl-tutorial)*

É um módulo do Spring Security e exige a criação de uma estrutura de tabelas no seu banco de dados. Se você não tiver esse tipo de restrição, acredito que vale dar uma olhada.

Até!

Comment: Olá! Esse módulo é bastante promissor. Infelizmente, o projeto em que usei tal esquema de segurança já foi há uns 2 anos e as tabelas foram definidas pelo cliente. Bolaram um esquema tão confuso que nenhum framework iria (querer) suportar. Talvez desse pra ter feito um misto das abordagens. Mas obrigado de qualquer forma. :D

Comment: Opa! Foi um prazer. Se tiver mais alguma coisa pra colocar dá um toque. Segurança é sempre uma parte delicada de qualquer projeto e as pessoas tem mania de negligenciar ou pensar que é fácil, mas na verdade o buraco sempre é mais embaixo.