# Struts2 com plugin Oauth2 do Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, struts2, oauth2

Gostava de saber se é possivel usar o plugin Oauth2 do Spring Security com Struts2 ou se esse plugin tem alguma restrição que só permite funcionar no SpringMVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como a maioria dos projetos Spring, não há restrição de uso do Spring Security com outros frameworks, inclusive para projetos *desktop*. A ideia do Spring Security não é de um *plug-in* a mais no Spring MVC, mas um componente independente.

Só para exemplificar, atualmente estou usando o Spring Security em um projeto com JSF. Neste projeto a segurança é aplicada através de um *filter* da API de Servlets, sendo então compatível com qualquer tecnologia web baseada em Servlets, tal como Spring MVC, JSF, Struts2, vRaptor, JAX-RS, JAX-WS, etc.

Por outro lado, em algumas partes eu precisei invocar a API programaticamente, isto é, chamando métodos diretamente, então o Spring Security pode ainda ser usado em qualquer projeto Java, mesmo desktop. Veja [este artigo](http://sacrephill.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/using-spring-security-in-a-swing-desktop-application/), por exemplo.

Minha única observação é considerar se as funcionalidades providas pela API estão de acordo com os requisitos do seu sistema. O Spring Security é bom, mas muitas vezes será necessário estender suas funcionalidades. Veja [uma questão minha sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185/como-criar-permissoes-permissions-de-verdade-ao-inves-de-simples-papeis-roles).