# Mudar a role do spring-security pelo bean

Tags: java, spring-security

Estou usando o `spring-security` para autenticar meu usuário, até ai beleza, agora eu quero poder trocar a role do usuário pelo `managed bean`, alguém tem uma ideia?

Tipo tenho varios modulos e cada usuario tem um role para cada modulo entao quando ele clicar no modulo quero pegar o usuario da sessão ver no banco qual é a role dele e setar dai direcionar para o modulo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja eu tenho uma tela onde o usuario loga no sistema e aparece os modulos que ele tem acesso mas não carreguei as permissoes dele em cada modulo quando clicar no modulo quero ai ir no banco e pegar a role que tem acesso a esse modulo, abaixo o exemplo de tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

vocês vão ve que tenho um usario logado com a role role_root e quando ele clicar no SAR ele tem que ter a role_usuario.

Comment: Paulo, não entendi uma coisa. Você quer mudar a *role* dinamicamente, isto é, acrescentar novos papéis a um usuário logado? Ou seria somente a questão de verificar se o usuário tem permissão para acessar o recurso XPTO?

Comment: Isso acrescentar novos papeis, porque um usuario que tem a role_admin em um modelo as vezes ele é role_usuario em outro

Comment: Paulo, não é assim que o Spring funciona. Neste caso, você deve usar roles independentes. Exemplo: `role_admin_feature_1` e `role_admin_feature_2`.

Comment: dei uma editada para ve se fica mais claro

Comment: Ok, nesse caso você deve fazer mais ou menos o que fiz na minha [outra questão sobre Spring Security](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2054/227), isto é,  substituir o mecanismo de decisão por uma lógica completamente sua. Nesse caso, não precisa injetar as roles no Sprign Security, basta carregar os dados do banco e executar a lógica baseando-se na área do sistema sendo acessada pelo usuário. Nesta implementação é possível acessar os dados de sessão e requisição.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada obrigado

Comment: Uma alternativa seria você criar uma list de strings com todas as roles que o usuário possui, e todo seu sistema funcionar 'lendo' se a sua list contém a role exigida, isso funcionaria para todas as permissões do sistema, e caso desejasse, poderia incrementar seu list em tempo de execução, inserindo ou removendo novas permissões. Se estiver usando spring fica bem simples utlizar esta funcionalidade alterando o autenticate e ou athorization. Acha que isso atenderia sua necessidade?

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver seu problema você terá que implementar `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` e validar pelas url's chamadas.

```
Para isso adicione em suas configurações: 

    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.exemplo.security.RequestInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

E implemente o mesmo:

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {


        if (request.getServletPath().endsWith("/login"))
            return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);

        // não validar requisição de arquivos do resources. CSS, JS
        if  (request.getServletPath().startsWith("/resources/")) {
            return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
        }


        // valida URL
        String urlRequest = request.getServletPath();

        // faz sua regra de negocio

    }
}
```

Pega do banco de dados a area do sistema que o usuario pode acessar e valida se a url corresponde a area que o usuario pode acessar.